# ¿Cómo colocar nombres de las filas en una matriz de una función?

Tags: r, rstudio, apply

He creado la siguiente función.

```
estadisticos<-function (x) {
  media<-mean(x, na.rm = T)
  mediana<-median(x, na.rm = T)
  desv.s<-sd(x, na.rm = T)
  minimo<-min(x, na.rm = T)
  maximo<-max(x, na.rm = T)
  CV<-desv.s/media
  tam<-sum(!is.na(x))
  tab<-round(matrix(c(media,mediana,desv.s,minimo,maximo,CV,tam)),3)
  row.names(tab)<-c("MEDIA","MEDIANA","DESV.STAND.","MÍNIMO","MÁXIMO", "COEF.VARIACIÓN","N")
  tabla1
}
```

como se puede ver, con la función `row.names()` he agregado los nombres a mi matriz `tab`. Al usar la función con sólo un vector me resulta genial. Aparecen los nombres de las filas.

```
estadisticos(sample(1:1000,500, T))
                  [,1]
MEDIA          498.734
MEDIANA        508.000
DESV.STAND.    290.674
MÍNIMO           1.000
MÁXIMO         999.000
COEF.VARIACIÓN   0.583
N              500.000
```

Pero a la hora de usarlo con un `apply` para obtener el resultado de varias columnas a la vez ya no me arroja los nombres de las filas.

```
df<-data.frame(t=sample(1:500,300,T),r=sample(1:100,300,T),u=sample(1:200,300,T))

apply(df, 2, estadisticos)
           t       r       u
[1,] 249.333  50.473 105.710
[2,] 243.500  51.000 106.000
[3,] 141.354  27.406  57.541
[4,]   1.000   1.000   1.000
[5,] 500.000 100.000 200.000
[6,]   0.567   0.543   0.544
[7,] 300.000 300.000 300.000
```

**Cómo podría especificar en la función para que los nombres de las filas se mantengan cuando uso un** `apply` o `sapply`. No externamente, sino dentro de la función.

**Muchas gracias de antemano**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un comportamiento de la función [`apply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/apply) que no está relacionado con el objeto de entrada. Por ejemplo, con un simple vector, podemos constar que los "nombres" de los estadísticos se "pierden" igual:

```
> x <- cbind(sample(1:1000,500, T))
> apply(x, 2, estadisticos)
         [,1]
[1,]  491.740
[2,]  495.500
[3,]  292.939
[4,]    1.000
[5,] 1000.000
[6,]    0.596
[7,]  500.000
```

En la documentación de [`apply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/apply), leemos:

> In all cases the result is coerced by as.vector to one of the basic
> vector types before the dimensions are set

Es decir, todo resultado obtenido luego de aplicar la función, en este caso `estadisticos` se pasa por un [`as.vector()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/vector), que en la ayuda menciona:

> if the result is atomic all attributes are removed.

Es decir, todos los atributos (los nombres de fila lo son) serán removidos. En el contexto del funcionamiento de  [`apply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/apply) es razonable este comportamiento.

Para resolver lo que buscas, puedes optar por `lapply()` que te retonará una lista que mantiene los atributos, la cual podrás transformar fácilmente en una matriz:

```
do.call(cbind,lapply(df, estadisticos))

                  [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
MEDIA          242.793  51.200 101.907
MEDIANA        238.500  51.500 101.500
DESV.STAND.    146.363  28.490  56.744
MÍNIMO           1.000   1.000   1.000
MÁXIMO         500.000  99.000 200.000
COEF.VARIACIÓN   0.603   0.556   0.557
N              300.000 300.000 300.000
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.